# Google maps API v3 infoBubble with array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps-api-3, infobubble

Has anyone seen or know of good examples of Google maps v3 infoBubble examples?

I am looking at using an array of data for it but cannot seem to fathom if there are any good uses out there or if it works for a simple array of data set out with JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

Have you seen this Example, from google maps api documentation

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple-max

OR a little complicated one:

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/smartinfowindow/smartinfowindow.html

Comment: yes these are the generic ones but the styling is awful and very hard to change when it comes to creating a completely custom infoBubble from scratch